# How to make a whatsapp share button that picks the URL automatically

Tags: html, button

I have implemented the Whatsapp share button on my site

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=add text URL" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><button>WhatsApp Share</button></a>
```

But as you can see I have to place the text and URL of the post every time I write and publish a new piece of content.

Is there a way that I can use this WhatsApp button where it can automatically pull the URL whenever someone clicks on share. (i don't wanna use any plugin)

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to store your url and text in some state variable and each time you can update state and the url and text on button function will update automatically.